# face-api.js load image file from disk

Tags: node.js, face-api

I tried the following to load an image from disk using face-api.js:

```
faceapi.fetchImage(path.resolve(INPUT_DIR, 'input1.jpg');
```

It throws the following error: `Error: fetch - missing fetch implementation for nodejs environment`

Is there any other way of load image from disk and displaying using nodejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it fails because you need to implements the fetch function for it to work. `FetchImage` should be used when you are trying to retrieve the image from online. If you are using the image from local disk, then do this:

1. Load the modules from local disk.

   ```
   await faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromDisk(path.join(__dirname, 'models'));
   ```

   // for me, I have put all the modules in src/models/
2. Load the canvas
3. Pass the canvas and modules option (if any)

   ```
   let detectionresult = awaitfaceapi.detectAllFaces(canvas, this.getSSNMobileOptions())
   ```

Comment: Actual code rather than pseudo code would have been more-helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/#face-apijs-for-nodejs) recommends you use the [**canvas**](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) to do something like this:

```
const canvas = require('canvas');
faceapi.env.monkeyPatch({ Canvas, Image })
const img = await canvas.loadImage('./img.jpg');
const detections = await faceapi.detectSingleFace(img);
```

`fetchImage` [will not work with local files](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/issues/369#issuecomment-518094313):

> `faceapi.fetchImage` as the name implies uses fetch under the hood, thus it doesn't work with filepaths to local files.

Comment: Can I pass the image URL in loadImage function to get buffer as well?